# Multiple rows in XSL output

Tags: for-loop, xslt, foreach

```
From the XML below, I am trying to achieve this final output
XML
<root>
<Primary_Key>12345</Primary_Key>
<First_Name>ABC</First_Name>
<Last_Name>DEF<Last_Name>
<Bank_Account>
<Bank_Name>ABC Bank</Bank_Name>
<Bank_Account_No>123456</Bank_Account_No>
</Bank_Account>
<Bank_Account>
<Bank_Name>DEF Bank</Bank_Name>
<Bank_Account_No>789012</Bank_Account_No>
</Bank_Account>
<Organization>Pharma</Organization>
<Organization>Inventory</Organization>
</root>
```

The output that I want to see is :

12345,ABC,DEF, ABC Bank,123456,Pharma
12345,,,DEF Bank,789012,Inventory

So, basically every field that has multiple values needs to be populated in the next row with the other fields that have multiple values. If there was a 3rd organization named "Supply" then the output should've been

12345,ABC,DEF, ABC Bank,123456,Pharma
 
12345,,,DEF Bank,789012,Inventory
12345,,,,,Supply

Not able to get my head around how will we loop around to fetch the data

Comment: "*basically every field that has multiple values needs to be populated in the next row with the other fields that have multiple values.*" You need to clarify if there is one field - e.g. `Organization` - that will always have the maximum number of values.

Answer (score 2):

This is an easy step

```
   <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="//Organization">
        <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()"/>
        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(parent::root/Primary_Key, ',' , parent::root/First_Name[$pos], ',' , parent::root/Last_Name[$pos], ',' , parent::root/Bank_Account[$pos]/Bank_Name, ',' , parent::root/Bank_Account[$pos]/Bank_Account_No, ',', current())"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I like this solution better than mine, though it assumes that `Organization` elements will always outnumber `Bank_Account` elements which may or may not be true for the OP's code. It also outputs an unnecessary new line character at the start that could be fixed with `<if test="$pos > 1">`.

Comment: To accomodate what @PatrickDark is pointing out, I am taking the count of each field at the start and using the highest count of those in my for loop.

Answer (score 1):

Create a template around `Primary_Key`. Use that to run a row generation loop on `Bank_Account`. If the number of `Organization` items exceeds the number of `Bank_Account` items, run additional row loops. If necessary to avoid duplication (e.g., because you're using an identity template), call an empty template on every non-`Primary_Key` element.

```
<transform xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <output method="text"/>
    <template match="child::Primary_Key">
        <variable name="organizations.outnumber.bank.accounts" select="count(following-sibling::Bank_Account) &lt; count(following-sibling::Organization)"/>
        <for-each select="following-sibling::Bank_Account">
            <variable name="row.number" select="position()"/>
            <value-of select="concat(preceding-sibling::Primary_Key/child::text(), ',')"/>
            <choose>
                <when test="$row.number = 1">
                    <value-of select="concat(preceding-sibling::First_Name/child::text(), ',', preceding-sibling::Last_Name/child::text(), ',')"/>
                </when>
                <otherwise>,,</otherwise>
            </choose>
            <value-of select="concat(child::Bank_Name/child::text(), ',', child::Bank_Account_No/child::text(), ',')"/>
            <if test="count(following-sibling::Organization[position() = $row.number]) = 1">
                <value-of select="following-sibling::Organization[position() = $row.number]/child::text()"/>
            </if>
            <if test="not(self::Bank_Account[position() = last()]) or $organizations.outnumber.bank.accounts">
                <text>&#xa;</text>
            </if>
        </for-each>
        <if test="$organizations.outnumber.bank.accounts">
            <variable name="row.start.number" select="count(following-sibling::Bank_Account) + 1"/>
            <for-each select="following-sibling::Organization[position() >= $row.start.number]">
                <variable name="row.number" select="position()"/>
                <value-of select="concat(preceding-sibling::Primary_Key/child::text(), ',,,,,')"/>
                <value-of select="self::Organization[position() = $row.number]/child::text()"/>
                <if test="not(self::Organization[position() = last()])">
                    <text>&#xa;</text>
                </if>
            </for-each>
        </if>
    </template>
    <template match="child::root">
        <apply-templates select="child::Primary_Key"/>
    </template>
</transform>
```

If using an identity template, use `<template match="child::Primary_Key/following-sibling::*"/>` to nullify the remaining elements.